# White noise assumption in the autocorrelation proof

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, white-noise

I followed the proof presented in *Quantitative Risk Management: Concepts, Techniques and Tools* by D. Duffie, S. Schaefer (proposition 4.9, pages 128-129).

To arrive at the numerator for the autocorrelation expression they state that, since $\varepsilon_t$ is $WN(0,\sigma^2_\varepsilon)$ white noise, it follows that $\mathbb E(\varepsilon_{t-i}\varepsilon_{t + h - j}) \neq 0 \iff j = i + h$.

I don't get fully how they arrive at $j = i + h$. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Doesn't expression $E(\epsilon_{t-i}\epsilon_{t + h - j}) \iff j = i + h$ miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula $ ~ \mathbb E(\varepsilon_{t-i}\varepsilon_{t + h - j}) \neq 0 \iff j = i + h$ is derived from white noise assumptions:

- **Assumption**: $Cov(\varepsilon_s, \varepsilon_r) = 0 $ for every $s\neq r$:

  - Any two different epsilons are uncorrelated, then they satisfy the condition: $Cov(\varepsilon_s, \varepsilon_r) = \mathbb E(\varepsilon_s \varepsilon_r) - \mathbb E(\varepsilon_s) \mathbb E(\varepsilon_r) = 0$ for every $s\neq r$.
- **Assumption**: $\mathbb E(\varepsilon_t) = 0$ for every $t$:

  - Assuming this, we can simplify above condition to: $\mathbb E(\varepsilon_s \varepsilon_r) = 0$ for every $s\neq r$.
- **Assumption**: $Var(\varepsilon_t) = \sigma^2 < \infty$ for every $t$:

  - Then we know, that $Var(\varepsilon_t) = \mathbb E(\varepsilon_t^2) - \mathbb E^2(\varepsilon_t) = \mathbb E(\varepsilon_t^2) \neq 0$.

So $E(\varepsilon_{t-i}\varepsilon_{t + h - j}) \neq 0$ can happen *if and only if* the two epsilons inside the expected value are the same random variable, and this happens only for $ - i = h-j $.

The same holds when the white noise is assumed an I.I.D. process.

Comment: I see. This holds for a strict white process, a variation of the white process. But what if the $\epsilon_i$ are not independent, i.e. for the more loose definition of the white process?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Of course I should use word uncorrelated instead of independent. It is more general then. Lack of correlation means covariance equal to zero, which means $E(XY)-E(X)E(Y) = 0$, which for zero means leads to E(XY) = 0.